# Insert element in html using java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to insert a button into my html using javascript,
I read this tutorial : [javascript.info/tutorial/modifying-document](http://javascript.info/tutorial/modifying-document)
and made this simple example to test it : [jsfiddle.net/XuAfA/86/](http://jsfiddle.net/XuAfA/86/) 
but it's not working ... Here is the code of the example if you don't want to open the url :

```
var bibi = document.getElementById('bibi');
var s = document.createElement('button');
s.innerHTML = "toto";
document.insertBefore(s, bibi);
```

and my html :

```
    <ul id="Parent">
       <button id="bibi"> hello wrold ! </button>
    </ul>
```

I can't see why this is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insertBefore` is executed on the parent element of the element you want to insert before

```
parent.insertBefore(toInsert, child);
```

As the document contains the body which contains the elements etc. you can't use `document` as the parent element, you should be doing

```
bibi.parentNode.insertBefore(s, bibi);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/0ddhty72/)

Answer (score 0):

Next code explains the difference between INNERHTML and CREATE ELEMENT to add a button :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Insert element</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

function btn_inner () {
var bibi = document.getElementById( 'bibi' );
bibi.innerHTML = "<input type='button' value='I was created with INNERHTML ! ! !' />";
}

function btn_create () {
var bibi = document.getElementById( 'bibi' );
var obj;
obj = document.createElement( "input" );
obj.type  = "button";
obj.value = "I was created with CREATE ELEMENT ! ! !";
bibi.appendChild( obj );
}

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="btn_inner()">Click here to insert button with INNERHTML</button>
    <button onclick="btn_create()">Click here to insert button with CREATE ELEMENT</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div id="bibi"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Create a textfile, rename it TEST.HTML (or any name), then copy-paste previous code, save the file and double click it to open it in a browser.